# istream::operator>>(int&) seems to behave weirdly with whitespaces

Tags: c++, stl

for some reason operator>> is behaving weirdly in my program.

This is the code:

```
ifstream fs;
fs.open(filename, ifstream::in);

if (!fs)
{
    cout << "File could not be read" << endl;
    return;
}

string input;
map<int, pair<Vec3, int> > skeleton;

while (getline(fs, input))
{
    stringstream ss(input);

    cout << "stream " << ss.rdbuf() << endl;

    int nodeId(-1);

    ss >> nodeId;
    cout << "stream " << ss.rdbuf() << endl;
    cout << "nodeId " << nodeId << endl; \\program stops before outputting "nodeId"

    Vec3 nodePosition(1);

    ss >> nodePosition;
    cout << "stream " << ss.rdbuf() << endl;

    int prevId(0);

    ss >> prevId;
    cout << "stream " << ss.rdbuf() << endl;

    skeleton[nodeId] = pair<Vec3, int>(nodePosition, prevId);
    cout << ss.rdbuf() << endl;
}
```

My file looks like this:

```
0 -0.0647035 54.1029 0.645867 -1
1 4.25456 48.2454 1.73375 0
2 5.94451 27.2658 -0.00329354 1
3 6.5392 4.91011 -2.80206 2
...
```

- each line is `int float float float int`, separated by a space, at the end of the line a `\n`.

Idea: I want to read that file into a map, each line separately, so I use `getline` to read a line and then put that line into a stringstream. I now want to read each of the 5 numbers, save the first in an int, the next three into a `Vec3` (which is just vector in 3D space, for which operator>> is correctly overloaded) and the last in an int again, so I use `ss >> nodeId`, `ss >> nodePosition` and `ss >> prevId`.

Problem: The program stops at the indicated line. It doesn't crash or give any exception, it just stops. This is the output:

```
stream 0 -0.0647035 54.1029 0.645867 -1
stream
```

After which it just halts and does nothing. Looking at the debugger (I put the breakpoint at the line with the comment), the stream seems to be empty (`_Chcount` is `0`), and it did not seem to have written anything into `nodeId` either, because that's still `-1`.

Expected Behavior: `getline` reads a single line from the file (without the `\n`) at the end. Each call of `istream::operator >> (int&)` extracts characters until it reaches a whitespace (like all other similar stream operators), interprets the extracted characters as a number and saves it into `nodeId`.

I know I could just use `find_first_of` with `input` and convert that into a number, but I want to know where I'm going wrong here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the program with a debugger?

Comment: @Barmar I just did. Opposed to my previous perception, it doesn't seem to halt (even tho it still doesn't output anything aside from the two lines shown above), because the debugger allowed me to step through the code, but it still doesn't write anything into the variables, and the the stringstream seems to be empty after the first operator>> call.

Comment: Are you sure those are ordinary spaces, not some other Unicode character that looks like a space?

Comment: Which compiler do you use?

Comment: Those symptoms suggest that constructing `ss` failed the second time through the loop. Look at the value of `input`.

Comment: The very first `cout << ss.rdbuf()` call reads `ss` all the way through to end-of-file. Any attempt to extract more characters from it would fail. This would explain why, say, `nodeId` remains unchanged, though I don't see why the program would block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot read from stringstream, because your logs messes the ss buffer. 
`cout << ss.rdbuf();` read the ss until the end and moves its position to end of the buffer.

Just remove logs `cout << ss.rdbuf` in your code and it will work as expected.

If you want to use `rdbuf` anyway, you can do this:

```
stringstream ss(somestring);
int pos = ss.tellg(); //store the position
cout << ss.rdbuf() << endl;
ss.seekg(pos); //restore position
```

Edited according to Igor Tandetnik comment.

Comment: It's not `ss.rdbuf()` that changes the position. It's `operator<<` in `cout << ss.rdbuf()`. This reads characters from `ss` and outputs them to `cout`; naturally, afterwards there are no more characters to read.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thanks for details. I found out this after posting answer. Simple call to `rdbuf` doesn't move the position, only when `cout << ss.rdbuf()`

Comment: Oh my, I didn't think of that, that's a pretty stupid mistake then, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code

```
fs.open(filename, ifstream::in);

if (!fs)
{
    cout << "File could not be read" << endl;
    return;
}

string input;
map<int, pair<Vec3, int> > skeleton;

while (getline(fs, input))
{
    stringstream ss(input);

    int nodeId(-1);
    ss >> nodeId;
    cout << "nodeId " << nodeId << endl;

    Vec3 nodePosition(1);
    ss >> nodePosition;

    int prevId(0);
    ss >> prevId;

    skeleton[nodeId] = pair<Vec3, int>(nodePosition, prevId);
}
```

do not print stringstream content using rdbuf() function